# could I use Alias in View in SQL Server and process?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

could I use Alias in View in SQL Server and process in it?

for example, I have :

```
select dbo.DateToShamsi(dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate) as HK2Hijri .....
```

can I Use :

```
select dbo.DateToShamsi(dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate) as HK2Hijri , SUBSTRING(----->HK2Hijri, 1, 4)
```

if No how can I Do That?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> could I use Alias in View in SQL Server and process in it?

No, explanation [All-at-Once Operations in T-SQL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx)

> *Invalid column name 'Corrected FirstName'.*
>
> This error message means that we cannot use an alias in next column expression in the SELECT clause. **In the query we create a corrected first name and we want to use it in next column to produce the full name, but the All-at-Once operations concept tells us you cannot do this because all expressions in the same logical query process phase (here is SELECT) are evaluated logically at the same time.**

---

You could use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT s.HK2Hijri, LEFT(s.HK2Hijri, 4)
FROM dbo.Health_Komak2 k
OUTER APPLY (SELECT dbo.DateToShamsi(k.CDate) AS HK2Hijri) s
```

Comment: @Mohammad It depends on your function, but it won't be slower than `SELECT func()`

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can do this using a subquery, CTE, or lateral join.  Let me show the latter, which is the most fun of the options:

```
select v.HK2Hijri, substr(v.HK2Hijri, . . .
from dbo.Health_Komak2 hk outer apply
     (values (dbo.DateToShamsi(hk.CDate))
     ) v(HK2Hijri);
```

Apply is handy because you can define multiple aliases.  You can also use `apply` multiple times to perform operations on previously defined aliases.